# How do I know inside the program that the non-consumable IAP is in review?

Tags: ios, review, in-app-purchase

I have a newsstand magazine app, and besides the auto-renewable subscription, we also want to provide the non-consumable IAP for users who doesn't subscribe to buy each single issue. The problem is, each time we publish a new issue, we need to set up an IAP in iTunes Connect, and submit it for review.

Before the IAP is approved, when the users try to download the issue, it always report the error "Cannot connect to the iTunes store", which is from the SKPaymentTransaction's error. Is there anyway I can detect inside the program that the IAP is in review, so I can popup a better alert like "This issue is being reviewed, please wait" other than the confusing error message from the SKPaymentTransaction? For example, can I check the NSError.domain or NSError.code to find out if the error means that the IAP hasn't approved yet?

Thank you in advance. Any suggestion or clue would be appreciated!